# unity 3D - How to fill a form and send it to an email address

Tags: forms

I have an app for Android and iOS.
I'd like to fill a form and send it to an email address.
Basically, it's to get some feedback.

But first, is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using C#, yes this is possible.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041926/sending-email-from-inside-unity3d) might help you. [One of the answers claim to have a working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21061469/2034041) as follows:

> I just successfully sent an email from Unity 3D using the following code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

using UnityEngine;

public class SendMail : MonoBehaviour {
    public string sender = "me@mymailaccount.com";
    public string receiver = "me@mymailaccount.com";
    public string smtpPassword = "mysmtppassword";
    public string smtpHost = "mail.mymailacount.com";

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start() {
        using (var mail = new MailMessage {
            From = new MailAddress(sender),
            Subject = "test subject",
            Body = "Hello there!"
        }) {
            mail.To.Add(receiver);

            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpHost) {
                Port = 25,
                Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)new NetworkCredential(sender, smtpPassword)
            };
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```